# How do i get dataframe 1 in the form of dataframe 2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: DataFrame 1]

[image: dataframe 2]

How do i get dataframe 1 in the form of dataframe 2?

Comment: do `df1['tests'].explode()`

Comment: `df1.explode('tests')`